# Can I install ADFS Service and ADFS Web Proxy on same server

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

We have a running ADFS Service with Office 365 on one of our production box. Now we want to expose our ADFS to ASP.NET Applications as well. My understanding is that I have to install ADFS Web Proxy to do it.

My question is, Can I do it on the server where ADFS service is configured? or Do I have to have a separate server?

Answer (score 1):

No - you have to have a separate server.

Typically the Web Application proxy (WAP) is in the DMZ while ADFS is behind a firewall.

In general, adding ASP.NET claims-enabled applications to ADFS does not require installing WAP.

Are these non claims-based? External?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Yes, these are for external parties. and we will need few claims.

Comment: I am wondering how it will working without proxy, https/servername/adfs/ls is not even available without proxy?

Comment: Yes it is but it doesn't do anything. Try the metadata URL. Both the proxy and ADFS have the same URL. Typically, you have a split DNS and externally resolves to the proxy and internally resolves to ADFS.